# About "static" in C, how is it implemented by the compiler?

Tags: c

About "static" in C, how is it implemented by the compiler ?

This is a Bloomberg interview question. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Since static has various different meanings, depending on context, it's a pretty bad question.

Comment: @Paul: Unless the context was clear in the original question, but the asker here has left it out.

Comment: @Andrey: No, a static modifier on a global variable is very different from a static modifier on a function local.

Comment: @Andrey: for a start there are static variables and static functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[[I'm assuming we're talking about `static` in the context of variables here, because `static` functions are simply a compile/link-time thing, with no run-time implications.]]*

In short, it's implementation-specific.  The compiler is free to do anything it chooses.

Typically (but by no means exclusively), statics are stored in the [.bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) or [.data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) sections of the executable image at fixed locations.  This has performance advantages, as they can be accessed with literal addresses, rather than pointer dereferences (as would be the case for stack-based variables).  As this is part of the binary, this also means that the initial values are automatically mapped into memory when the executable is first loaded; no intialisation routines are required.

Comment: @Andy Leman it is not stupid. for these types of questions right answer is 1) you can tell how any specific compiler does it 2) if you don't know think how would you implement it.

Comment: Perhaps they were meaning one of the other uses of `static`.

Comment: @Andy, Perhaps the answer they wanted was "static in what context"?  It's implementation-specific is generally a safe answer, but maybe they just wanted to test awareness of the different meanings of the word "static" depending on the current context.

Comment: They're only stored in the `.bss` section if the data is not initialized; if the static data is initialized, it usually lives in the `.data` section (under classic memory models).

Comment: This is not really a stupid interview question, though it may be stupidly worded. If you can't explain the pros and cons of static (both as a linkage and as a storage duration), you probably can't write good C code. (For instance, your code might very well pollute the global namespace, make key functions non-reentrant, non-threadsafe, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

**static global variables** will generally be allocated a fixed address at compile time.  Many OS provide memory regions that are 0-initialised, others that map part of the executable image with preinitialised data, as well as totally uninitialised areas.  Depending on whether the compiler can work out the correct initial content of the static variable at compile time, it may select the most appropriate of these memory regions, calling any run-time initialisation later if required.  For example:

```
static int x;  // needs to be 0 before main() runs
               // best way: 0-initialised memory area
static int y = 3; // best way: map/copy area of executable already containing "3"
static int z = time(NULL); // initial value unimportant
                           // best way: uninitialised memory area
                           //           pre-main() init code
```

Notes: putting e.g. `z` in 0-initialised memory then clobbering it is not significantly wasteful - just not strictly necessary.  Some OS may have separate areas for read-only/const values.

**static local variables** with compile-time known initial values *may* be created as per globals.  For run-time initialised values (only legal in C++) compilers tend to (must?) initialise them when the scope is first entered.  This is typically coordinated by having an implicit supporting boolean value per scope containing static local variables: each time the scope is entered the boolean is consulted to see whether the statics need to be initialised.  On some compilers, this may actually be done in a less efficient but thread-safe fashion, such that static locals can be used for singleton instances.

EDIT: Given Lundin's comment (correctly) asserting all C statics must be initialised before `main()`, I wrote some code to explore this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void f()
{
    static int i = time(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    int i = time(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    sleep(2);
    f();
}
```

With GCC's C compiler, I get a fatal compilation error about the local `static i` requiring initialisation at run-time.  Compiled as C++ (my main language), this is perfectly legal and initialised at run-time and after entering `main()` - showing that that part of my explanation above is only relevant to C++.

**static functions** are simply marked in the generated object such that the linker won't consider them when matching unresolved calls from other objects.

Comment: For all static variables (and global variables), the compiler *must* ensure that they are initialized *before* main() is called. Even static variables that aren't explicitly set to a value by the programmer, *must* be initialized to zero or NULL. This is required by ISO C.